# SQL: How to use 'LIKE' with a date 'between'?

Tags: sql, mariadb

So, i´m trying to select rows between two dates.
In db, the dates also have time.
Therefor i need to use LIKE.

**SQL**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE date >= LIKE :selectedDateFrom AND <= LIKE :selectedDateTo";

$query_params = array(':selectedDateFrom' => $selectedDateFrom.="%", ':selectedDateTo' => $selectedDateTo.="%");
```

This one returns error!
How should it look like?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (ANSI SQL has BETWEEN to find values between two dates.)

Comment: ìm using Mysql MariaDb

Comment: @jarlh If i use between it works. But if i select 1st of oct. The result will start at 2nd oct?

Comment: I suppose you have to either compare dates without the time part, or start at 00:00:00, and end at 24:00:00.

Comment: @jarlh You mean 23:59:59 :-)

Comment: @RacilHilan, perhaps, I don't know MySQL/Mariadb very well. (ANSI SQL has time until 24:00:00.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In db, the dates also have time.
>   Therefor i need to use LIKE.

No, you don't.

To select all date/times where the date component is between (from) and (to), inclusive, you can write it as

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE date >= :selectedDateFrom
AND date < :selectedDateToPlusOne
```

(Note the `<` instead of `<=`, and set the second parameter to one day *after* the last day you want to include in your results.) This works even when the column includes times.

Comment: Why no "="? If i select 1st to 30nd i only got 1st to 29th?

Comment: @Mjukis Yes, which is why you set the "to" parameter to one day later. Hence the "PlusOne" I added to its name. :) Edited to draw more attention to it.

Comment: Yes i noticed that. I have to add one day before i make the querry!?!

Comment: @Mjukis Yes, it's actually pretty common for ranges to be inclusive on the lower end, but exclusive on the upper end. The range of a zero-based array of 10 elements could be described as [0..9], or as [0..10), for instance, and while a textual description would normally use the former, code actually typically ends up using the latter.

Comment: I found this: SELECT DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 DAY); How can i add it to my querry?

Comment: @Mjukis That doesn't make sense in the context of your question. You have `selectedDateTo` as a parameter which is not necessarily "today". The easiest way would be to get "one day later" from your PHP code (it is PHP, right?) using the `date_add` function. If you do insist on doing it from SQL, you should be able to change the second operand of `<` to a `DATE_ADD` expression exactly in the style of your comment, except changing `CURRENT_DATE` to your parameter.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use like with dates in SQL
SO use this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE date >= :selectedDateFrom AND date <= :selectedDateTo";
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd strip the time part from a datetime with `DATE()`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE date(mydate) >= :selectedDateFrom 
AND date(mydate) <= :selectedDateTo;
```

Or with `BETWEEN` for better readability:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE date(mydate) BETWEEN :selectedDateFrom AND :selectedDateTo;
```

Comment: I do not have to strip my variables they are: "YYYY-MM-DD" It´s db who is datetime. Therefor i added a wildcard to my vars. "%". What is: "(mydate)"?

Comment: Worth noting: filtering on `date(mydate)` means that even if the table has an index on `mydate`, that index cannot be used. I recommend searching on plain `mydate` as in my answer, but another way of avoiding the problem could be creating an index on `date(mydate)`, if MariaDB supports that. (I know some database implementations support it, I don't know about MariaDB specifically.)

Comment: @Mjukis: I named your table mytable and your date mydate, because `table` and `date` are reserved SQL words. You said that "the dates also have time". I assumed this to be the column you are talking about. However, to get rid of the time part use `DATE()`, so you can compare the dates without the time part.

Comment: @hvd: That's true. With `date(mydate)` no index can be used. I don't know whether MariaDB would use it on BETWEEN dates either, though. A functional index in MariaDB can be achieved with an index on a computed column.